# Different distance in .jpg plot and .eps

Tags: legending, plotting, eps-format

I noticed that when I run my code to draw a plot:

```
ListPlot[{valAlpha, tk100},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[85]],
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {"Number of non-zero bits", "alpha"},
 Axes -> False,
 FrameTicksStyle -> Thick,
 LegendShadow -> None,
 PlotLegend -> {Style["exact value", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 180], 
   Style["estimated value", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 180]},
 LegendSpacing -> 2.0,
 LegendOrientation -> Horizontal,
 LegendSize -> {1.3, 0.15}, LegendPosition -> {-0.83, 0.55},
 LegendBorder -> White,
 LegendTextOffset -> {-0.8, 2.0},
 PlotRange -> {0, 10},
 ImageSize -> 7500,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

I have different distance between labels in legend. 
First picture show plot saved as `.jpg`, and the second as `.eps`

[image]

[image]

How can I set the distance between label 'exact' and 'estimated' to be as close as in the first pic, but using format .eps to save the plot?

Comment: Since V9 `PlotLegend` has been superseded by the much better built-in option `PlotLegends` (note the 's' at the end). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* uses the style environment specified by the `ScreenStyleEnvironment` FrontEnd option for on-screen rendering and `Export`ing into raster formats but for printing and `Export`ing into PostScript formats it uses the style environment specified by the `PrintingStyleEnvironment` option. They have different values by default:

```
Options[$FrontEnd, {PrintingStyleEnvironment, ScreenStyleEnvironment}]
```

> ```
> {PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout", 
>  ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"}
> ```

If you set `PrintingStyleEnvironment` identical to `ScreenStyleEnvironment` then EPS and PDF figures will look exactly as on the screen:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

---

See this Toolbag answer for more information: "[General PDF/EMF export problems and solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124065/590388)."

P.S. I recommend to use lossless PNG format for `Export`ing if you need your plot as a raster image: JPG format is lossy and designed for storing photos, it introduces artifacts into scientific drawings.