# How can I control the overall size of a labeled plot?

Tags: plotting

I am creating a bar chart plot and would like to set the overall its over size to be 240 pt, or approx. 85 mm in width and use automatic aspect ratio. Before I add the axes labels, the size looked all right. However, after I add the axes labels with `Labeled[...]`, the oversize became smaller than what I expected.

The codes I used before and after adding the axes labels are

```
BarChart[spec // N, 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[list, Above], GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.2}}, BarSpacing -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 240]
```

and

```
Labeled[
  BarChart[spec // N, 
    ChartLabels -> Placed[list, Above], GridLines -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.2}}, BarSpacing -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 240], 
  {"Harmonic order", "Harmonic mag. [p.u.]"}, 
  {Bottom, Left},
  Spacings -> {0.2, -0.2}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

The bar charts I exported in pdf format and placed side by side with the same percentage display, they look like

[image]

Why is the one with axes label much smaller? How do I correctly set the overall size of the second plot to be 240 pt also? Sorry the codes above include some predefined variables, but I guess this is a general question about how to control the overall size of a plot with `Labeled[...]`.

Comment: Although you are asking a general question, it is good practice to include ***all*** the definitions needed to make your examples executable by other people so they can generate answers in terms of the those examples.

Comment: Also, you have been asking questions on this site for two months; it is time you learned to format your questions properly. A way of learning how to format is to click on the edit button at the bottom of any well-formated question or answer, and study its formatting. When I was new to this site, I learned a lot about formatting that way.

Comment: Correct response is a duplicate to [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65933/44141)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Labeled` objects are not treated consistently with other graphics objects in *Mathematica*, so I would recommend avoiding `Labeled` for precise work.

To match the appearance of `Labeled` you can use `Frame` and `FrameLabel`:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 240, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Harmonic order", "Harmonic mag. [p.u.]"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the whole image will be at the size you specify.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) them prior to exporting:

```
spec = {.1, .2, .5, .3, .9};
list = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
p1 = Rasterize[
  BarChart[spec // N, ChartLabels -> Placed[list, Above], 
   GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.2}}, 
   BarSpacing -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 240], ImageResolution -> 300]
p2 = Rasterize[
  Labeled[BarChart[spec // N, ChartLabels -> Placed[list, Above], 
    GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.2}}, 
    BarSpacing -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 240], {"Harmonic order", 
    "Harmonic mag. [p.u.]"}, {Bottom, Left}, Spacings -> {0.2, -0.2}, 
   RotateLabel -> True], ImageResolution -> 300]
Export["p1.pdf", p1]
Export["p2.pdf", p2]
```

Comment: If the Head of `p2` was `Graphics` (as `p1`), not `Labeled`, one can use 'set' of `ImagePadding` + `BorderDimensions` to make pictures of equal size and to have nice vector pdf images, not raster (although 300 dpi is appropriate). Why MMA gives different types (heads) to similar objects? For simple user both these charts look like Graphics objects.

Comment: @Stitch Sorry, I need the figures to be in vector format and cannot rasterize them. Any idea why the size became so much smaller after adding `Labeled`?

Comment: @nanjun Then you have to look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65933/44141) for the exact solution to your problem. Short story --  `PrintingStyleEnvironment` has to be `Working`.

Comment: On the othe hand, if OP uses these plots (*.pdf files) in some document (e.g. LaTeX) they can be scaled without any loss in quality to needed size when placed even if originally they were of different sizes.